Sharing file download url between microservices
I'm having trouble thinking of a better way to handle file downloads in a micro-services architecture.
We have a micro-service that generates a report and sends the download url to the results micro-services like so:
{
...,
id: "056b99d5-5983-4e63-8eb4-ccccc46c10b7",
report_download_url:"https://reporter-api.staging.services.com/reports/22f6bdc8-1c64-4c378018-47579d1b369b/download",
...
}

The results microservice frontend directly calls the reporter service to download the file using that url. This feels slightly weird to me. Should the report micro-service be sending a url pointing towards the report service or maybe the S3 bucket where the actual file is being stored?
Thanks!

What's "weird" about it? I don't think there's a single correct answer, only many different opinions on how to approach this (and your approach apparently works)

Sorry, I forgot to mention that access to these files should be restricted to people who have access to that file. By accessing another microservice directly, you’ll have to share that access knowledge between the services when the reporter service should be generic

microservices are independent services, rather than sharing the url. Please allow to download the file itself, because by sharing url microservice will be dependent on another service. Security will also be not there if you share the url, which can expose certain details.
